# How to add objects to a already instantiated JList in Java?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, jlist

I want to add objects to a JList which has already been instantiated by the Netbeans genrated code.

I can't pass my own list model in the JList constructor as I can't modify the Netbeans generated code.

How can I add object to that JList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment to nfechner, it really depends on how you've constructed your JList.  If you've used the `JList(ListModel)` or `JList(Vector)` constructors you can potentially amend the consents of your model through a call to `getModel()`, or in the case of `Vector`, simply maintain a reference to the `Vector` and amend that (providing you fire an event aftewards to notify any model listeners).

However, I'm fairly sure there are "hooks" in the Netbeans IDE to allow you to specify a specific model implementation, which will then cause the code to be auto-generated to include this.

Comment: The Netbeans generated the JList by passing the AbstractListModel. And I didn't find the way change the model so that it can generate that JList acc. to that model...

Answer (score 0):

Modify the generated list model. You can get it via:

See [JList#getModel()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getModel())

Comment: This will only work if you've constructed the JList with a ListModel or Vector.  Instantiating is using the default constructor or Object[] will create a read-only ListModel.

Comment: You're right, of course. In that case you would probably have to set a new model.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to set your own model to the already instantiated JList, see [JList#setModel(ListModel)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#setModel%28javax.swing.ListModel%29)

You can pass the model extended from DefaultListModel, which supports add and remove methods.